# Swing: JPanel on JScrollPane - how to jump and move focus to show a specific part of the panel

Tags: swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I have a very long jpanel on a jscrollpane.

I want to be able to jump to a location in the panel. 
is there a way to jump to a specific point in the pane?

Setting the horizontal scrollbar value is not enough 
Is there a way to mark a position and jump to it (rather than giving X,Y)? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [scrollRectToVisible](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#scrollRectToVisible%28java.awt.Rectangle%29) for scrolling.
Not sure what you mean with "mark a position" but if you want to scroll to for example a text field that is a (direct) child of the panel than you would do:

```
panel.scrollRectToVisible(textField.getBounds());
```